# Is it possible to use AJAX and PHP with a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Sorry if this is a total noob question, I am in fact a noob, haha. I have searched the internet to death on this but I can't find an answer.

First: I'm using a LAMP stack to run a website on my ubuntu server. It has an active MySQL database. I have a basic javascript module that draws to an html canvas that runs a little mini browser-based game (similar to old school pokemon). Generic, I know, but this is all for learning.

The game page is a php document where GameLoop.js runs/draws to the canvas. This works.

What I'd like to do is access the database with get/post queries without reloading the page. I have read that my options are either AJAX or some sort of API calls. I looked into AJAX but all I can find is how to populate forms and stuff on html pages, and I can't see anything that specifically references javascript of type 'module'.

Psuedo code of what I'm trying to do via the getPets.js (which main will call when certain triggers happen):

```js
export function getPets() {
    var pets = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GetPets.php",
        data: "", // pass userid or whatever data that php file might need
        dataType: "json",

        success: getPets(data) {
            pets.push(data[0]);
            pets.push(data[1]);
            pets.push(data[2]);

            return pets;
        }
    });
}
```

the GetPets.php:

```html
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
else {
    $petslist = [];
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ActiveCreatures WHERE OwnerID='$userid'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($stmt)>0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $petslist[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($petslist);
}
?>
```

In the main game loop js:

```js
import { getPets } from "./GetPets.js";

// rest of code

const pets = new getPets(userid);
```

I am doing this to learn php, mysql and javascript, but I'm super new to it and I'd really appreciate a bit of insight from you pros. Thank you so much, please be kind. <3

Comment: *"Psuedo code of what I'm trying to do"* - When you actually attempt this functionality in your code, what happens?  It's not clear to me what actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @David sorry for the lack of clarity, I haven't actually tried the code itself, since I'm not really sure how I should even write it. I suppose that's my biggest issue here. The getPets.js code is full of errors on my editor so I couldn't run it to begin with. I just don't know how I'm supposed to write it.

Comment: The `$.ajax()` call will not "return" the value from the server and assign it to `pets`. `$.ajax()` is an _asynchronous_ operation, i.e. browser calls it now, puts it aside, and then comes back to it when the response is received and when JavaScript is not busy. I recommend getting familiar with [asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous). I also recommend using native [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it is totally possible to use AJAX within a JavaScript and PHP.

Your PHP script, GetPets.php, seems correctly set up to return it in JSON format.

However, you should consider some points:

1. The AJAX request within getPets.js looks mostly fine, But, you should ensure that the data you're sending to GetPets.php is ready
2. AJAX requests are asynchronous. What it means? that the $.ajax call won't return the data immediately. Instead, it handles the data in the success callback function. So, you can't return pets from getPets() like a regular function. Try to use promises or async/await
3. In your JavaScript and PHP, add error handling to manage any unexpected situations.

your getPets function considering asynchronous behavior:

```
export async function getPets() {
    try {
        const response = await $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetPets.php",
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching pets:', error);
        return [];
    }
}
```

And in your loop, try do something like this:

```
import { getPets } from "./GetPets.js";

// all your code

async function loadPets() {
    const pets = await getPets();
    // Use pets here
}

loadPets();
```

Comment: Oh my gosh this is perfect! Thank you so much! Works perfectly <3! Sorry for such a newbie question but I appreciate you so much!